# set table random value from table

Tags: random, lua, lua-table

I have the following code:

```
wrg = { "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png" };

table = { }

for i = 1, 4 do
    table[ i ] = wrg[ math.random( 1, #wrg ) ]
end

for i = 1, 4 do
   print( table[ i ] )
end
```

output:

```
4.png
2.png
4.png
4.png
```

I don't need repeat "4.png" how fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [random permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation). For instance, this code:

```
wrg = { "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png" };
t = {}

n=#wrg
for i=1,n do
    t[i]=wrg[i]
end

math.randomseed(os.time())

for i=1,n-1 do
    local j=math.random(i,n)
    t[i],t[j]=t[j],t[i]
end

for i=1,n do
   print(t[i])
end
```