# random scenes using array in corona sdk

Tags: lua

. . , I have a problem running random scenes using composer.gotoScene, only the first scene of the application is displaying in random form. This is a quiz game and i do not know how to call the result.lua with the score.

actual test:

```
1st attempt = scene2, scene3, scene4, scene1
2nd attempt = scene3, scene4, scene1, scene2
3rd attempt = scene4, scene1, scene2, scene3
```

expected output:

```
1st attempt = scene3, scene1, scene4, scene2, result
2nd attempt = scene1, scene4, scene2, scene3, result
```

here is my code for shuffle:

```
local sceneNames = {"scene1","scene2","scene3","scene4"};
for count=1, 0 do 
    sceneNames[count] = count
end



local function shuffle(t)
    local iterations = #t
    local j
    for count = iterations,2, -1 do
        j = math.random(count)
        t[count], t[j] = t[j], t[count]
    end
end

shuffle(sceneNames)
```

I do not know where to set this up or what i need to do. . . please help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25695927/107090.

Comment: possible duplicate of [set table random value from table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695807/set-table-random-value-from-table)

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to seed. This should work:

```
local sceneNames = {"scene1","scene2","scene3","scene4"}

local function shuffle(t)
    local iterations = #t
    for count = iterations,2, -1 do
        local j = math.random(count)
        t[count], t[j] = t[j], t[count]
    end
end
```

To use, run

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
shuffle(sceneNames)
```

multiple times. Each time, do

```
for i,v in ipairs(sceneNames) do print(i,v) end
```

to see that the sequence changes randomly each time.